# #<Closure> in output

Tags: scheme, closures

I was writing a function to switch the last element of a list to the beginning:

```
(define last-elem
    (lambda (l)
        (car (reverse l))))

(define all-but-last
    (lambda (l) 
            (reverse (cdr (reverse l)))))


(define (last-to-first x) (append (list last-elem x) (all-but-last x)))

(last-to-first '(1 2 3 4 5 6))
```

It didn't work and I knew why. I forgot to put the brackets around `list last-elem x`

The thing is, I was curious about the output of the wrongly-typed code:

```
(#<Closure> (1 2 3 4 5 6) 1 2 3 4 5)
```

What is the meaning if this? How did it come out to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Racket, the output is

```
'(#<procedure:last-elem> (1 2 3 4 5 6) 1 2 3 4 5)
```

which is a little clearer.

A reference to a function is always stored with its referencing environment, a.k.a. as a closure, and your Scheme implementation chooses to display it that way.

Answer (score 0):

```
(list last-elem x)
```

doesn't call the function `last-elem`. It simply returns a list of two elements: the value of the variable `last-elem` (which is a procedure) and the value of the argument `x`. You want:

```
(list (last-elem x))
```

But there's no reason to make a list in the first place. Try:

```
(define (last-to-first x)
  (cons (last-elem x) (all-but-last x)))
```

Comment: You correctly addressed the error in the code. But you didn't answer the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

In Scheme, all identifiers denote either a syntactic keyword (bound to a 'transformer') or a variable (bound to a value).  In your code `last-elem` denotes a variable bound to a function, which you defined.  When you write:

```
(list last-elem x)
```

the interpreter/compiler produces a list with the value of `last-elem` and `x`.  Thus, the result of `#<Closure>` in the list.